# HTTPS in MIDLET

Tags: java, java-me, ssl-certificate

I have developed an app which hits the url which is secured.when I hit this url using "https" I get "Certificate is expired" in simulator or "Certificate failed verification" in real device. below is the snippet of the code:

```
String loginUrl= "https://myhost.com/somefile";
 HttpConnection httpConn = null;
                DataOutputStream dataOS = null;
                System.out.println("strModuleName.trim()::::"
                        + strModuleName.trim());

                httpConn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(loginUrl);//, Connector.READ_WRITE);
                httpConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
                        "Profile/MIDP-2.0, Configuration/CLDC-1.0");
                httpConn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
                httpConn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);         
                dataOS = (DataOutputStream) httpConn.openDataOutputStream();
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use HttpsConnection instead of Http...?

Comment: tried with HttpsConnection class but still getting the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using HTTPS, the device need to validate the Certificate Chain that your server (myhost.com) has installed. If the certificate is expired, then you need to inform this to the webmaster so he can fix it.

If the certificate chain is correct, then the device has to validate it against the certificates that the device itself has installed. It's usual that mobile devices have certificates from the main certificates authorities (Verisign and others). But if your server's certificate is not installed in the device, you need to install it first to make the HTTP connection.

Comment: I have imported server certificates in device via wtk "manage certificates" but still its not working

Comment: How about the server's certificate? Have you tried verifying it in http://www.ssltool.com/?